# Cannot group by timestamp_trunc

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this query in standard sql.

```
select timestamp_trunc(endTime, MONTH), count(1)
from `simple_table`
group by timestamp_trunc(endTime, MONTH);
```

Which returnts the following error:

SELECT list expression references column endTime which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:24]

However, the following code:

```
select timestamp_trunc(endTime, MONTH)
from `simple_table`
limit 10
```

Works perfectly.  Is there some hidden reference about BigQuery's ability to do group by that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do as below

```
select timestamp_trunc(endTime, MONTH), count(1)
from `simple_table`
group by 1
```

or

```
select timestamp_trunc(endTime, MONTH) as m, count(1)
from `simple_table`
group by m
```

I think what happens is not the problem in using functions/expressions in GROUP BY, but rather the fact that engine does not recognize that expression for field in SELECT list and expression in GROUP BY are the same. Rather they are treated as different, thus engine think `endTime` filed is "orphan" (neither aggregated nor grouped by)

for example, below will work (of course it is not what you need - but it proves that group by accepts expressions)

```
select count(1)
from `simple_table`
group by timestamp_trunc(endTime, MONTH)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just co-figured this out.  That. Is. Crazy.  Is that really the sql 2011 standard for group by now?

Comment: added reply in answer

Comment: See also the [feature request for repeating an expression in the GROUP BY list](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=814).

Comment: thank  you Elliott. I didn't see this feature request before. so I was right with my explanation of the issue.